# Render multiple charts one after another in same page in JSF

Tags: javascript, jsf, charts, highcharts

I have a JSF page. There are four charts in that page. It is taking a bit long time to load and render the page because of big data. Is there any way, so that I can render the first chart during initial load of the page and all the other charts will be rendered after rendering the previous chart.

What could be the efficient way to load and render the charts very fast.

Thanks!

Comment: The answer depends heavily on what you are using to render the charts. Client-side rendering (e.g. Canvas, Flash, Silverlight) or server-side?

Comment: I am using highcharts to render charts. Getting data from Oracle DB and put all data in arrayList and then pass that to highcharts to render data.

Comment: Yes, you can do that.

Comment: How can I do that? @watson....

Answer (score 2):

Highcharts is fireing a [load-event](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events.load) when the chart is finished loading. Use this event for triggering the next Charts:

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
    ...
        events: {
            load: function(event) {
                initNextChart();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I don't know if loading the data or rendering the charts takes too much time but in the first case you should think of also loading the data for the next charts in `initNextChart()`.